# Stuck figuring out what assembly function does

Tags: function, assembly, analysis

I know this question is a little general, but I've been going through a large assembly file and I'm up until this function is called:

```
CPU Disasm
Address   Hex dump          Command                                 Comments
004149E0  /$  55            PUSH EBP
004149E1  |.  89E5          MOV EBP,ESP
004149E3  |.  83EC 28       SUB ESP,28
004149E6  |.  895D F4       MOV DWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.3],EBX
004149E9  |.  8B45 08       MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[ARG.1]
004149EC  |.  8975 F8       MOV DWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.2],ESI
004149EF  |.  897D FC       MOV DWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.1],EDI
004149F2  |.  8B00          MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EAX]
004149F4  |.  8945 E0       MOV DWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.8],EAX
004149F7  |.  8B40 F4       MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EAX-0C]
004149FA  |.  8945 E4       MOV DWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.7],EAX
004149FD  |.  8945 F0       MOV DWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.4],EAX
00414A00  |.  8B45 0C       MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[ARG.2]
00414A03  |.  890424        MOV DWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.10],EAX          ;string => [ARG.2]
00414A06  |.  E8 35C9FFFF   CALL <JMP.&msvcrt.strlen>                ;MSVCRT.strlen
00414A0B  |.  8945 EC       MOV DWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.5],EAX
00414A0E  |.  89C3          MOV EBX,EAX
00414A10  |.  8D45 EC       LEA EAX,[LOCAL.5]
00414A13  |.  3B5D E4       CMP EBX,DWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.7]
00414A16  |.  72 03         JB SHORT 00414A1B
00414A18  |.  8D45 F0       LEA EAX,[LOCAL.4]
00414A1B  |>  FC            CLD
00414A1C  |.  8B08          MOV ECX,DWORD PTR DS:[EAX]
00414A1E  |.  8B75 E0       MOV ESI,DWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.8]
00414A21  |.  8B7D 0C       MOV EDI,DWORD PTR SS:[ARG.2]
00414A24  |.  39C9          CMP ECX,ECX
00414A26  |.  F3:A6         REPE CMPS BYTE PTR DS:[ESI],BYTE PTR ES:[EDI]
00414A28  |.  0F92C0        SETB AL
00414A2B  |.  0F97C2        SETA DL
00414A2E  |.  28C2          SUB DL,AL
00414A30  |.  0FBEC2        MOVSX EAX,DL
00414A33  |.  85C0          TEST EAX,EAX
00414A35  |.  75 05         JNZ SHORT 00414A3C
00414A37  |.  8B45 E4       MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.7]
00414A3A  |.  29D8          SUB EAX,EBX
00414A3C  |>  8B5D F4       MOV EBX,DWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.3]
00414A3F  |.  8B75 F8       MOV ESI,DWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.2]
00414A42  |.  8B7D FC       MOV EDI,DWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.1]
00414A45  |.  89EC          MOV ESP,EBP
00414A47  |.  5D            POP EBP
00414A48  \.  C3            RETN
```

This function is really giving me a hard time, if you guys have any insights at all or can give me a general idea of what's happening with it I'd really appreciate it.

I am guessing it might have something to do with the size of a string being checked (maybe for a length of 10 chars?) Also from what I've seen (again, not sure) AL and EAX are the ones in this code that I'm really worried about.

If more information is needed about any parts of this please don't hesitate to ask me.

Comment: I'm afraid "What does this large chunk of uncommented assembler do?" isn't a good fit for SO.

Comment: essentially, it is moving data around, and compares and calculates a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, unoptimized x86 (not x86-64) assembly is pretty ugly (and in intel-syntax to boot... ugh)
Anyway, it seems this function takes the `strlen()` of a string, then takes the smaller of this strlen and a parameter passed in an array or struct, and uses it as the length-parameter for a `strncmp()`. The result of the strncmp is returned.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation got me figuring out what's going on.